# Using Ada, using instance of Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions(Real), calculating Nth root and output same

Tags: ada

Using Ada 2018 (increment of 2012), within a loop structure, I need to calculate the Nth root of Integers.

1. In my package `combinations.ads` specification declaration (using GNAT GPS), I have

```
type Real           is digits 6;
```

2. In package body `combinations.adb`, I have a procedure build, where before the begin, I instantiate Ada’s `Generic_Elementary_Functions(Float)`, with

```
package Fermat_math is new
   Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions(Real)  ;
   use Fermat_math
```

Later, in output section, I try:

```
-- -------------- buggy, fix
--   combo_sum_root := Fermat_math.Exp (Log (Integer(combo_sum_root) / n);  — n is integer type
     combo_sum_root := Real(combo_sum) ** (1/n) ; 
-- -------------

   put(" and sum's root is ");
   put(combo_sum_root'image );  —  -- gives all roots as 1.00000E+00
```

I had it working a few weeks back, with roots = 3.878… etc., but I lost that in careless version control.

Actual Code here:

```
— combinations.ads specification ------------------------------------------
with gearbox;
use  gearbox;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO  ; use Ada.Float_Text_IO;

with Ada.Text_IO;  use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics; use Ada.Numerics;

with Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions;
use  Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions;

package combinations is

type combo_action   is (add_element,clear, show, show_sum, Build);
type Real           is digits 6    ;

combo_sum_root      : Real         ;
i,n,b, combos_cnt
,combo_sum          : integer      ;

procedure get_parms                ;
Procedure build  (b,n,r:integer)   ;

end combinations;

-- combinations.adb BODY ---------------------------------------
with Text_IO              ;  use Text_IO;
with Ada.Text_IO          ;  use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.INteger_Text_IO  ;  use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;  use Ada.Strings.UNbounded;
with gearbox              ;  use gearbox;
with Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions ;

package body combinations is

group, Intersection_count,r     : Integer              ;
done, get_value                 : boolean := false     ;
CR: constant Character := Character'Val (13)           ;
type gear_arrays is array(positive range <>) of integer;

-- ------------------------------------------------------------


procedure get_parms is
begin
...

 end get_parms ;

-- --------------------------------------------------
 procedure build  (b,n,r: Integer) is
-- --------------------------------------------------
cnt, e_cnt, value                : integer :=0      ;
launch, pause                    : character        ;
run_again                        : String := " "    ;
show_group                       : Unbounded_string ;
all_done, combo_done             : boolean := false ;
combo_sum_root                   : Real             ;
progress_string : Unbounded_String                  ;
gears:gear_array     (1..r)                         ;

-- with Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions   ;  — in specification .ads file
 package Fermat_math is new
  Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions(Real)  ;
 use Fermat_math                                   ;

begin
...
...

put("Selecting "); -- put(tot_combos, width=>1);
put(" Possible Combinations,"); New_line;
While Not all_done loop  -- for all/x combiNatioNs
 ...  
end loop;
   -- ------------------------
   combo_sum := 0;
   for e in  1..r loop  -- select r value, element of grou & size of combiatios
     value := fermats(gears(e).position,1);
     ...
   put ("Combination sum is "); put (combo_sum, width => 1);
  …..
  -- -------------- buggy, fix
--   combo_sum_root := Fermat_math.Exp (Log (Integer(combo_sum_root) / n);
 combo_sum_root := Real(combo_sum) ** (1/n) ; 
  -- -------------

   put(" and sum's root is ");
   put(combo_sum_root'image );  -- gives all roots as 1.00000E+00

   end loop;

     group := group + 1;  --
   end if;  -- is New group and shift
  end loop;  -- Not all doNe

 eNd build;
begin   -- package
 Null;
end combinations;
```

Answer (score 3):

The critical issue in your example is that "n is integer type." When you try to create a [rational exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Rational_exponents), your expression `1/n` evaluates to an `Integer` with value zero. The package [`Generic_Elementary_Functions`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-5-1.html#p42) requires that "Exponentiation by a zero exponent yields the value one."

The solution is to use the type `Real` when creating your exponent: `1.0 / Real(N)`. Expanding on @Jim Rogers' [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72960993/230513), the code below also illustrates calculating the [*power via the logarithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_via_logarithms):

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions;

procedure Nth_Root is

   type Real is digits 6;
   package Real_Functions is new Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions
     (Real);
   use Real_Functions;

   N     : constant Natural := 2;
   Power : constant Real    := 1.0 / Real(N);
   Base  : constant Real    := 2.0;

begin
   Put_Line ("√2:" & Real'Image (Sqrt (Base)));
   Put_Line ("√2:" & Real'Image (Base**Power));
   Put_Line ("√2:" & Real'Image (Exp (Power * Log (Base))));
end Nth_Root;
```

Console:

```
√2: 1.41421E+00
√2: 1.41421E+00
√2: 1.41421E+00
```

Answer (score 2):

The "**" operator in Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions provides you with the ability to find the Nth root of a floating point number.

The following example compares use of the sqrt function and the "**" operator.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions;

procedure Main is
   type Real is digits 6;
   package Real_Functions is new Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions(Real);
   use Real_Functions;
   
   base  : Real := 2.0;
   Power : Real := 1.0 / 2.0;
begin
   Put_Line("sqrt of 2.0 is: " & Real'Image(sqrt(base)) & " and " &
              Real'Image(base**Power));
end Main;
```

The result of this example is:

```
sqrt of 2.0 is:  1.41421E+00 and  1.41421E+00
```

The exponent for the "**" operator is simply the inverse of N.

Edit: Adding the manipulations to calculate an integer root of a number.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions;

procedure integer_roots is
   function int_root (Num : Positive; Exponent : Positive) return Natural is
      type Real is digits 6;
      package real_functions is new Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions
        (Real);
      use real_functions;
      Real_Num      : Real := Real (Num);
      Real_Exponent : Real := 1.0 / Real (Exponent);
      Real_Result   : Real := Real_Num**Real_Exponent;
   begin
      return Natural (Real'Truncation (Real_Result));
   end int_root;

   Num      : Positive;
   Exponent : Positive;
begin
   Put ("Enter the base number: ");
   Get (Num);
   Skip_Line;
   Put ("Enter the root: ");
   Get (Exponent);

   Put_Line
     ("The" & Exponent'Image & "th root of" & Num'Image & " is" &
      Natural'Image (int_root (Num, Exponent)));
end integer_roots;
```

The function int_root shown above calculates the floating point root then converts the truncated result to the subtype Natural.

A sample execution of this program is:

```
Enter the base number: 10000
Enter the root: 20
The 20th root of 10000 is 1
```